# Loading Assembly and Type in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to dynamically load assemblies **at runtime** in .NET Core by essentially looking in an external folder and loading assemblies from there. Loading seems to work fine, however, i can't seem to instantiate the now loaded types in a .NET Core application.

I'm using the the following loading code (very basic for feasibility testing at this point):

```cs
private void LoadPrivateBinAssemblies()
{
    var binPath = Path.Combine(WebRoot, "PrivateBin");
    if (Directory.Exists(binPath))
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(binPath);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (!file.EndsWith(".dll", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
               !file.EndsWith(".exe", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                continue;

            try
            {
                var asm = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(file);
                //var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
                Console.WriteLine("Additional Assembly: " + file);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to load private assembly: " + file);
                Console.WriteLine("   " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note - I am using `AssemblyLoadContext.Default` to load into the .NET Core default context, from which I would presumably be creating a new type.

Then - for testing I now explicitly try to instantiate a type like this at the bottom of the `Configure()` startup sequence:

```cs
LoadPrivateBinAssemblies();

// this has my loaded assemblies in it
var list = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Assemblies;

try
{
    // this works
    var t = Type.GetType(typeof(Startup).FullName);

    // fails - Markdig is loaded and has no dependencies
    var t2 = Type.GetType("Markdig.Markdown", true);  // fails

    // fails 
    var md = Type.GetType("Westwind.AspNetCore.Markdown.Markdown", true);  
    // never get here
    md.InvokeMember("Parse", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, null, new object[] { "**asdasd**", false, false, false });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Log($"{ex.message}");
}
```

I've verified that the types exist in the assemblies and that the names are correct, but it fails on several custom loaded assemblies.

[image]

The figure shows the list of loaded assemblies (here from `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()`, but I get the same list from `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Assemblies`). The assemblies are loaded, but I can't get a type reference to the types contained within it.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Aug/30/Dynamic-Type-Invokation-in-NET

Comment: Ha ha that's funny you're referencing my own post - yes `GetTypeFromName()` from the post works as well for truly dynamic loading.

Comment: Just as a follow up to the base question here, I've create a blog post that specifically deals with loading assemblies in ASP.NET core and making them available to Razor Pages and MVC views: [Dynamically Loading Assemblies at Runtime for RazorPages](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Nov/05/Dynamically-Loading-Assemblies-at-Runtime-in-RazorPages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the assembly qualified name so, `Type.GetType("Namespace.TypeName, AssemblyName")`.

Comment: Thank you David - that does indeed work, and answers this question here.

But it wouldn't solve my actual problem which is making dynamically loaded assemblies visible to (runtime compiled) Razor pages in a 'normal' `namespace.class` format  or with a plain `using`. I suspect this isn't possible, but not within the scope of this discussion.